# Inheritance and access specifying

Tags: java, inheritance

I am new to the Java world and got doubt in working with one of the assignments.
I have a Base class reference and a private method in it, and a derived class in which the same method is overridden and with a public assess. Now when I started compiling this piece of code I am getting a compilation error. Can someone please let me know why this is happening:

CODE:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

class Base
{
    private void myfunc()
    {
        System.out.println("Base class");
    }
}

class Derived extends Base
{
    public void myfunc()
    {
        System.out.println("Derived class");
    }
}

class MyClass
{
    public static void main (String[] args) 
    {
        Base b = new Derived();
        b.myfunc(); // This line is giving compilation issue.
    }
}
```

And I am getting the following error:
error: myfunc() has private access in Base
        b.myfunc();
         ^

Answer (score 5):

You are getting this error because your object is defined as `Base`. This means that only the methods defined in `Base` will be available, even though you instantiated as `Derived`.

And obviously, `myFunc()` from `Base` cannot be accessed.

Instead, define it as the subclass:

```
Derived obj = new Derived();
```

Comment: If you want polymorphic type behavior then Base.myFunc will need to be public. If you don't want it to be accessed then consider making it both public and abstract or use an inteface instead of a class.

Answer (score 0):

When overriding a method, you cannot increase the visibility of that method. So when you override a private method, the overriding method must be private.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you cannot inherit `private` members of super class into subclass. So question of overriding it should never occur.

Next the compilation error you are getting is not related to inheritance at all. You have a private method in `class Base` which means you can only call it from the class itself and no where else. Since you are calling the method from `class MyClass` you are getting compilation error.

- So either change the visibility to public in superclass in which case you are overriding and correct method(of subclass) will be executed at runtime.
- Or Use subclass reference to create subclass object i.e Do not use `polymorphism`.

`Derived b= new Derived();`